# Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally

Tags: opencv, ros, slam

This is a problem I got when launching my own project,

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer
>   Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in
>   CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
>   /home/htf/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp,
>   line 505
>
> Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
>   exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
>   reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what():  /home/htf/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:505:
>   error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec
>   acutally. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

opencv version: 2.4.9

I am new to OpenCV, does anyone know how to fix this problem? Your clues would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you passed an unsupported `fourcc` argument to the `VideoWriter` class.
The list of supported values of `fourcc` for `CvVideoWriter_GStreamer` in OpenCV 2.4.9 can be found at: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp#L462.

Just out of curiosity, why are you using a self compiled version of OpenCV?

Comment: thank you for your reply. I changed the related files as what you said. using a supported fourcc named as  MP2V. but the problem still exists.